# Infinite Scroll, what's wrong?

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

No Java errors, Masonry is working, Infinite Scroll is activated in the theme, but don't know why it is not working:

http://prendaoffline.tumblr.com

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Your div#pagination must be out of your div#content, like this

```
<div id="content" class="masonry">
  <div class="posts masonry-brick">...</div>
  <div class="posts masonry-brick">...</div>
  <div class="posts masonry-brick">...</div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="pagination">
  <div id="nextPage"><a href="/page/2"></a></div>
</div>
```

It's not necessary the "»", keep it empty.

If you have your JS correctly this HTML code should work